# Is it possible to use a nodejs dependent library in Cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, cordova

I created an android project with Cordova and I found a javascript library that requires node.js to run. I know that Cordova runs with node.js so is it possible to call the library with Cordova?

Answer (score 1):

There are tools out there that let you use node-style modules on the front end. You may want to look into Browserify: http://browserify.org/